# For $r_n=0.2+0.3r_{n-1}$ defined recursively, how to show the limit of $r_n$ exists?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Suppose sequence $r_n$ is recursively defined as $r_n=0.2+0.3r_{n-1}$ for $n>0$ and $r_0=1$. I know that if $\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow\infty}r_n$ exists, then $\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow\infty}r_{n-1}=\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow\infty}r_n$ and let $A=\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow\infty}r_n$ and plug it in we will have $A=0.2+0.3A$ and hence $A=2/7$.

The problem is, how do we show the limit exists? $r_n$ is apparently bounded. But I don't know how to show it is monotone. $r_n-r_{n-1}$ gives $0.2-0.7r_{n-1}$, whose sign is dependent on $r_{n-1}$.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A method is the following: Your potential limit $A $ (equal $2/7$) satisfy (1) $A=0.2+0.3A$. Put $v_n=u_n-A$ and substract (1) from the recurrence relation, you get $v_n=0.3v_{n-1}$. An easy induction show that $v_n=(0.3)^n v_0$, and you are done.

Answer (score 2):

***Hints:***

- The function $f$ which takes in $r_{n-1}$ and returns the next term in the sequence is a monotone increasing function.
- Notice that $x_1 \gt x_2 \gt  0\implies f(x_1) \gt f(x_2) \gt 0$
- Use Induction to show the sequence $(r_n)$ is monotone.

Comment: Thank your for the reply, but I still get a problem, because the monotonicity is dependent on $r_{n-1}$. Let's assume $r_{n-1}>r_n$ holds for any $n$, but $r_{n+1}-r_n=0.2-0.7r_n=0.2-0.7(0.2+0.3r_{n-1})=0.06-0.91r_{n-1}$ is still dependent on $r_{n-1}$.

Comment: $0.06-0.21r_{n-1}$ is positive or negative, depending on whether $r_{n-1}$ is above or below $2/7$

Comment: @Tony: The induction step is as follows:- $$ r_n \lt r_{n - 1} \implies  0.3 r_n \lt 0.3 r_{n - 1} \implies 0.2 + 0.3 r_n \lt 0.2 + 0.3 r_{n - 1} \implies r_{n + 1} \lt r_{n } $$

Answer (score 0):

You can try the sequence $\{r_n-A\}_n$ which converges to zero.